# Efficient algorithm to search a tree and return a subset of the tree only including the results

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, treeview, subset

I have a tree in which every node has a name. I want to search through the node names and return a subset of the tree which only contains the found nodes and its parents.

Does anybody know an efficient algorithm for this problem? I searched a lot but I only found algorithms which only return the node but not the node with all of its parents.

---

Here is an example. I want to search for "CAT" and the tree looks like this:

- CAT

  - dog

    - fish
  - hamster
- hamster

  - CAT
  - dog

    - fish
- dog

  - fish

    - CAT
    - hamster
  - unicorn

---

The result should look like this:

- CAT
- hamster

  - CAT
- dog

  - fish

    - CAT

Comment: Store it's parent_id in the database as well?

Comment: Yes, the parentId is stored as well

Comment: Get all `CAT` names and loop trough each one doing a DFS to get the subtrees as answered.